# can't override onContextItemSelected in Fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment

I'm trying to convert Activity to a fragment and can't override this methods : `onCreateOptionsMenu`,`onOptionsItemSelected`,`onContextItemSelected`.
,maybe some import statements are missing ? don't know what to do.Her is my Class file :
package com.wts.ui;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    protected final static int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    public static WordsDBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private CustomAdapter cDataAdapter;
    private Button button;
    private EditText editWord;
    private EditText editTranslate;
    private ListView listView;
    private String selectedWord;
    private Cursor cursor;

    // context menu
    private final static int IDM_EDIT = 101;
    private final static int IDM_DELETE = 102;
    private final static int IDM_INFO = 103;

    // options menu
    private static final int IDM_ABOUT = 201;
    private static final int IDM_EXIT = 202;
    private static final int IDM_SETTINGS = 203;
    private static final int IDM_QUESTION = 204;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        dbAdapter = new WordsDBAdapter(getActivity());
        dbAdapter.open();

        displayListView();
        registerForContextMenu(listView);

        // ================ListView onLongClick========================
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                selectedWord = cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.ID_COL);
                return false;
            }
        });

        // ================Button onClick========================
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String word = editWord.getText().toString();
                String translate = editTranslate.getText().toString();

                if (word.length() > 0 && translate.length() >= 0) {
                    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchWordsByName(word);// chek is
                                                                        // word
                                                                        // repeat

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(R.string.word_exist),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (!CheckWordInput(word)
                            || !CheckTranslateInput(translate)) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.incorrect_input),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        dbAdapter.insertWord(word, translate, " ",
                                String.valueOf(false), 0, 0, new Date());
                        displayListView();

                        editWord.setText("");
                        editTranslate.setText("");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddWord);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listWords);
        editWord = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editWord);
        editTranslate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTranslate);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.listWords) {
            String[] menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(
                    R.array.contextMenuItems);

            menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_EDIT, Menu.NONE,
                    menuItems[StartActivity.CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT]);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_INFO, Menu.NONE,
                    menuItems[StartActivity.CONTEXT_MENU_INFO]);
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, IDM_DELETE, Menu.NONE,
                    menuItems[StartActivity.CONTEXT_MENU_DELETE]);

        }
    }

    //
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case IDM_EDIT: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.fstRow),
                    cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.WORD_COL));
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.scndRow),
                    cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.TRANS_COL));
            intent.putExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.thrdRow),
                    cursor.getString(WordsDBAdapter.DESC_COL));

            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
        }
            break;
        case IDM_DELETE:
            dbAdapter.deleteWord(selectedWord);
            displayListView();
            break;
        case IDM_INFO: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InformationActivity.class);
            for (int i = 1; i <= InformationActivity.nListItems; i++)
                intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(i), cursor.getString(i));

            startActivity(intent);
        }
            break;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        }
        return true;
    }

    private void displayListView() {
        // Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllTranslated();
        Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllTranslated();

        String[] columns = new String[] { WordsDBAdapter.KEY_WORD,
                WordsDBAdapter.KEY_TRANSLATION, WordsDBAdapter.KEY_SUCCEEDED, };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textViewTranslate, R.id.textViewWord,
                R.id.textViewSuccessPoints };

        cDataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.word_info,
                cursor, columns, to);

        listView.setAdapter(cDataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case IDM_ABOUT: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case IDM_EXIT: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            break;
        }
        case IDM_SETTINGS: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case IDM_QUESTION: {
            if (!StartActivity.isMainActivitySart)
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        QuestionActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (intent.hasExtra(getResources().getString(R.string.fstRow))) {
                dbAdapter.changeValue(
                        selectedWord,
                        intent.getExtras().getString(
                                getResources().getString(R.string.fstRow)),
                        intent.getExtras().getString(
                                getResources().getString(R.string.scndRow)),
                        intent.getExtras().getString(
                                getResources().getString(R.string.thrdRow)),
                        null, null, null, null);
                displayListView();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        SettingsManager.setPreferedLanguage(getActivity());// set language
        displayListView();
    }

    public static boolean CheckTranslateInput(String str) {
        Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L} -]{0,25}");
        Matcher inputMatcher = inputPattern.matcher(str);
        return inputMatcher.matches();
    }

    public static boolean CheckWordInput(String str) {
        Pattern inputPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{L} -]{1,25}");
        Matcher inputMatcher = inputPattern.matcher(str);
        return inputMatcher.matches();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        dbAdapter.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think about what you want your Fragment to be - `Fragment` or `SherlockFragment`?

You import this:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
```

And so, your overrides **aren't** overrides because `Menu` & friends are different classes right now than what `Fragment` needs - they are ActionBarSherlock's classes.

If you extend `SherlockFragment` instead, your overrides should work, and it is recommended to extend `SherlockFragment` if you are using ActionBarSherlock (which based on your tags, you are).

If you want to keep this as a regular fragment, then import:

```
android.view.Menu
android.view.MenuItem
android.view.MenuInflater
```